# Visual Studio 2022 ignores Targets property of ProjectReference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

So there are two csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2.csproj" Targets="CustomTarget" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
    <Target Name="CustomTarget">
        <Error Text="It works!"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

CustomTarget invokes well when I'm using `dotnet build`, or `dotnet msbuild`, or even
`msbuild`. But when I try Build\Rebuild in VS or Rider it is completely ignored. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: VS will run msbuild to build a project, so what you see from the command line should happen in the IDE as well.  But with one quirk, it will only launch msbuild when it is convinced that the project's source code has changed.  So if you are editing the project file and expect the changes to be effective then you'll find it doesn't work.  Use Build > Rebuild to force the build.

Comment: Rebuild doesn't work as well. ConsoleApp2 being rebuilt, but CustomTarget still not called. There is even nothing about this target in msbuild log

Comment: `dotnet build` is equivalent to `dotnet msbuild -target:build` and `msbuild -target:build`. An SDK style project is importing a set of files behind the scenes. The `build` target is supplied by the imported SDK files. When the `build` target is run I expect your `CustomTarget` is not run because `CustomTarget` has not been hooked into the chain of targets that run for `build`. I expect that `dotnet build` does not run `CustomTarget`. Change to something like `<Target Name="CustomTarget" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">`. cont...

Comment: See [Extend the Visual Studio build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @JonathanDodds I don't want to invoke CustomTarget after each ConsoleApp2 build. Instead, I want it beign invoked on dependent project build. That's what Targets attribute of ProjectReference meant for, I thought...

Comment: @Andrey Yes, I missed the point of your question.

Comment: @Andrey I can't speak to Rider but Visual Studio, to make the UI quicker and more responsive, attempts on its own to track which projects are up to date and doesn't just rely on MSBuild. Although the rationale is understandable this does cause behavior differences which is terrible. For an example see "[Customize the solution build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-solution-build?view=vs-2022)". I suspect the `Targets` metadata of `ProjectReference` is not often used and that you may have found a defect (or at least other behavior discrepancy).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also tackling this issue. However msbuild (CLI) and Visual Studio build doesn't behave identically when handling `ProjectReference`. It is documented at   [The ProjectReference Protocol](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/main/documentation/ProjectReference-Protocol.md)

> **GetTargetPath** should return the path of the project's output, but not build that output.
>
> - Conditions: **this is used for builds inside Visual Studio, but not on the command line.**
> - It's also used when the property BuildProjectReferences is false, manually indicating that all ProjectReferences are up to date and shouldn't be (re)built.
> - This should return a single item that is the primary output of the project, with metadata describing that output. See TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker for the default metadata.

> **Default** targets should do the full build and return an assembly to be referenced.
>
> - Conditions: **this is not called when building inside Visual Studio**. Instead, Visual Studio builds each project in isolation but in order, so the path returned from GetTargetPath can be assumed to exist at consumption time.
> - If the ProjectReference defines the Targets metadata, it is used. If not, no target is passed, and the default target of the reference (usually Build) is built.
> - The return value of this target should be identical to that of GetTargetPath.

I am looking for a solution.

Edit: Found the answer within `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`:

```xml
    <!--
        When building this project from the IDE, just gather the referenced build outputs.
        The IDE will already have built the project, so there's no need to do it again here.

        The ContinueOnError setting is here so that, during project load, as
        much information as possible will be passed to the compilers.
        -->

    <MSBuild
        Projects="@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)"
        Targets="GetTargetPath"
        BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)" ...>
...
    </MSBuild>
```

> **The IDE will already have built the project**

Alright, that means the referenced project must also be added to VS Solution. After doing that, the references finally builds correctly, yay.